# How to work around SAX Exception due to invalid element while using web service in client side?

Tags: java, web-services, sax

I have a web service client written in java. There is a change in WSDL in the server side due to an extra field that is added to an existing complex type field. But my client side has the stale WSDL which does not know this field, so when there is a web service call there is a SAX Exception due to that missing field. Is there anything I can do in my client side to get the other elements? Ignore that one element that is not conforming to the client code that I'm having?

EDIT : Normally when there is a change with WSDL, that should be communicated to client side, but when the change is not communicated in some situations, the system should be kept afloat. Hence the need for the work around.

Comment: You can't have one-sided contracts. If this is a new field added to the response you should be able to ignore it by turning off validation, but exactly how you do that will depend on the technology and specification of the consumer code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! I'm using Java as the client side handler. Do I have to play around with the generated client code by wsdl2java?